# Redirections all subcategory to a new page

Tags: customization, performance

I would  like to redirect all my subcategory  toa ne page, for example
Electronics category redirected to the same page then Computers subcategory redirected to the Computers page then > component pc subcategory on the components pc page.  Will this chain of redirections of categories and subcategories to new pages make the site load more difficult, its functionality slower or does it not affect the redirection in any way?
do redirects affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

Redirects do impact performance, especially if you start to stack them. You will likely get better performance by creating custom post types and taxonomies that build the exact URL and content structure you're looking for.